Data disappearing using ggarrange
I'm wanting to display 12 plots together using ggarrange, on their own each plot shows the data properly (boxplot) but when I use ggarrange I get them perfectly arranged, axis and labels, but no boxes or data on the graphs.
I'm essentially just using ggarrange(plot1, plot2, etc..., ncol=3, nrow=4)
I was hoping all 12 plots and stats would appear neatly on one exportable image but the graphs end up being empty
